# Mac App Store Sandbox File Exceptions Not Working

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I have a project in Xcode which is working as it should without sandboxing enabled, but I'm hoping to publish on the Mac App Store, so I need to enable sandboxing.

My application needs to write into another application's `~/Library/Application Support` folder, so I'm adding a temporary file exception into the Entitlements file - but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here's some detail:

- I've enabled App Sandbox in the target's Capabilities page;
- My `.entitlements` file has an array entry for `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write`. This has a single child, a string currently set to '/' (for test purposes - I'll narrow this down once I get it working);
- I'm setting my writing URL with the following, then appending appropriate path components to it:

  `let applicationSupportURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first`
- Despite this, I see my application is performing operations inside `/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/<appID>/Data/Library/Application Support/`...

I'm running Xcode 9.4.1 under macOS 10.13.6.

Any ideas?

Comment: FileManager.default.urls resolves to your own sandbox. To get to the "home-relative-path" you would have to use FileManager with relative path to user home ~. Your app will probably not be approved with temporary-exception. Use OpenPanel insted to ask user for permission to write into Application Support

Answer (score 0):

FileManager returns paths relative to an app's container rather than the user's real home directory when the sandbox is enabled.

Quinn “The Eskimo!” suggests using `getpwuid` to get the user's real home directory, like so:

```swift
func realHomeDirectory() -> URL? {
    guard let pw = getpwuid(getuid()) else { return nil }
    return URL(fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation: pw.pointee.pw_dir, isDirectory: true, relativeTo: nil)
}
```

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107593?answerId=327636022#327636022

This will allow access to paths configured  via `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.*`, but these exceptions may not be approved by App Store review.

> Next, let’s talk about App Review. To start, be aware that I don’t work for App Review, and thus I can’t make definitive statements on their behalf. However, my understanding is that App Review carefully audits any use of file access temporary exceptions. I’m skeptical that you’ll be able to convince them that your exception is justified.